# How to write to an Azure database with an Azure blob trigger

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am trying to pass values from a python data frame to an Azure SQL database using a blob storage trigger.

Here is my code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1};SERVER=[servername],1433', user=[user], password=[password], database=[database])
cursor = conn.cursor()    
insertQuery = '''INSERT INTO Test([FileName],[Score]) VALUES (?,?);'''
cursor.execute(insertQuery,mainDFRows[0])
conn.commit()
```

I have also tried using the following:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=[servername],1433', user=[user], password=[password], database=[database])
```

The code works well locally, however, when I deploy the azure function I receive the following message:

Exception: Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I am deploying the function with pyodbc in requirements.txt

Would really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong driver. Using {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} worked.